# This webpage has a redirect loop?

Tags: python, django, geoip

I want to redirect the request to the appropriate url depending on the Ip of the request. For that I'm writing a middleware.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
from teashop import settings as settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# IPs for Testing
# Indian IP : '182.75.107.138'
# Russian IP : '95.108.142.138'
# Chinese IP : '27.227.255.255'


class GeoRedirectionMiddleware(object):


    def process_request(self, request):
        """
        Detect Location using GeoIP
        """ 
        g = GeoIP()
        ip = '95.108.142.138'
        country_dict = g.country(ip)
        if country_dict["country_code"] == "RU":
           if '/ru' not in request.path:
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/ru'+request.path)
           else:
              pass
```

This redirects `'/'` to `'/ru/'` fine. But when I access some other url `'/abc'` it says Too many redirects.

My Middlewares

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'forked_apps.middleware.GeoRedirectionMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Do you have the GeoIP C library installed?

Comment: yes from shell I checked it's working fine

Comment: I think you are setting `LANGUAGE_CODE` wrong. Try `request.LANGUAGE_CODE='ru'`

Comment: Tried not working still .. don't know if its being set then reset

Comment: @RahulGupta changed the whole question body almost. Look now.

Comment: Have you tried printing the `country_dict` to see what values it actually contains?

Comment: `{'country_name': u'Russian Federation', 'country_code': u'RU'}`

Comment: What exactly do you mean not working? Let me guess an endless redirection loop?

Comment: Yes it says too many redirections